# unable to use inline in declaration get error C2054

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile some open source projects using the vs2013 c/c++ compiler. The file is .c extension. The below code returns some errors (below). All of which can be "fixed" by simply removing the inline in the declaration. Note: not a real function, just illustrative

```
static inline int pthread_fetch_and_add(int *val, int add, int *mutex)
{
    return 0;
}
```

errors
error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
error C2085: 'pthread_fetch_and_add' : not in formal parameter list
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

Comment: VS is not a fully standard-compliant compiler, so decent chances are that you would need to use your simple "fix" of removing `inline`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `__inline` with MSVC.

`inline` is a c99 keyword and c99 is not yet (fully) supported with MSVC.

> "The inline keyword is available only in C++. The __inline and __forceinline keywords are available in both C and C++. For compatibility with previous versions, _inline is a synonym for __inline."

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx

### Example

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus) && defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER < 1900
#  define inline __inline
#endif
```

> **Note** that `1900` means Visual-studio-2015,
> I mean, said version supports inline in .c files (so c99 standard is little more supported, but not fully).

Answer (score 8):

A simple workaround is to -Dinline=__inline with the MSVC compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Instead of changing every `inline` to `__inline`, I added the following before all of the function declarations:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define inline __inline
#endif
```

This would allow the original code to still be compiled as-is with a different compiler (that presumably didn't have the same limitations as the VS one).