# Why Cyclonedds cannot build for vs2013?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, build, visual-studio-2013, data-distribution-service

I am able to build [cycloneDDS](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds) for vs2019 and vs2017.

I need to build cycloneDDS for vs2013 express

CMake x64 vs2013

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" -A x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\king\Downloads\cycloneDDS_VS_2013_Build\cycloneDds_install_dir ..
```

tried following as well

```
 cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\king\Downloads\cycloneDDS_VS_2013_Build\cycloneDds_install_dir ..
```

tried following as well

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Users\king\Downloads\cycloneDDS_VS_2013_Build\cycloneDds_install_dir .. 

--> CMake Error: Error: generator : Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
```

but many errors appear when run

cmake --build . --target install

I have following

1. Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1
2. cMake 3.19.2
3. jdk1.8.0_281
4. apache-maven-3.6.3

   C:\Users\king\Downloads\cycloneDDS_VS_2013_Build\cyclonedds-master\src\ddsrt\include\dds/ddsrt/log.h(15
   1): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline' [C:\Users\king\Downloads\cycloneDDS_VS_2013_Build\cycl
   onedds-master\build\src\tools\ddsconf\ddsconf.vcxproj]**

and many errors, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyclone targets C99 but VS2013 is still lacking support for significant parts of that version of the C language.

The probable cause of the specific error you mention is [unable to use inline in declaration get error C2054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736304/unable-to-use-inline-in-declaration-get-error-c2054). The workaround given there is worth a try.